# Запрос на SQL server.Выдает ошибку

Tags: sql-server

Нужно найти за какой месяц спортсмен показал максимальный результат(показатель).
select distinct(ФИО),месяц,MAX(показатель) from оценивание,спортсмены
where спортсмены.id=оценивание.ФИО
 
group by ФИО,месяц;
Сообщение 209, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 352
Неоднозначное имя столбца "ФИО".
Сообщение 209, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 350
Неоднозначное имя столбца "ФИО".

Comment: Вы вот пишите distinct(ФИО) (distinct кстати не нужен и не применим одновременно с group by)  и group by ФИО. А из какой таблицы БД должна взять это поле ? Он не знает, потому что в обоих таблицах у вас есть такое поле (что странно). указывайте явно кое значение имеете ввиду `имя_таблицы.ФИО`

Comment: Select оценивание.ФИО, месяц,MAX(показатель) from оценивание,спортсмены
where спортсмены.id=оценивание.ФИО
GROUP BY ФИО, месяц;  И так пробывала

Comment: А в group by почему ФИО без указания таблицы ? Ставьте везде

Comment: И еще сравнивание id из одной таблицы с ФИО из другой смотрится ну ооочень странно, не ужели у вас в качестве id используются фамилии ?

Comment: Нет,я просто их связала

Comment: Сделала как вы сказали но,вывелись все результаты ,а не максимальный результат спортсменов

Comment: ну а большее и невозможно подсказать не видя структуры таблиц и не понимая что такое "показатель". вот вы берете max(показатель), а правильно это или нет сказать невозможно. Может вам надо за месяц суммарный получить, а может средний, а может еще какой и уже из полученного искать макимальный. В любом случае сначала получаем правильные данные по месяцам, потом оборачиваем это в еще один запрос, там нумеруем строки с помощью `row_number() over(partition by ФИО order by суммарный_показатель desc)`, оборачиваем это еще в один запрос и в нем уже отбираем первые записи

Comment: Получите в подзапросе пару (спортсмен - его максимальный результат), и используйте её в отборе полных записей в основном запросе.